# How to "merge" two fontello font files?

Tags: fontello

I'm making changes to an existing project that uses fontello.

And I would like to add some icons to the project's font file.

What is the easiest way to to add those new icons? Can I create a 2nd font file in fontello and then somehow merge the two font files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you download a Fontello pack it includes a `config.json` file, which is a mapping of the characters included in your custom font. If you want to add more characters to your font, you should start by uploading this config file to fontello.com, change your selected characters and then download a new pack, making sure to replace all the fonts and css files (so that the new characters start working) and this config file (for next time you want to change the set of characters included).

Comment: The only problem I have now, is that the existing project only has the font files. No config.json to be seen... :(

Comment: I see. Then to my knowledge there isn't much you can do than start from scratch, unfortunately.

Comment: Yep :(. Still I'll try to get in touch with guys that developed the initial project to see if they still have the config.json somewhere...

Comment: Had to start from scratch, but I'm using your suggestion to manage new icon additions

Comment: Bummer. I hope from now on the process will be smoother.

Comment: Definitely. Thanks again.

Comment: You can drag the svg version of the font file to fontello and rebuild your package. Also remember the original .zip file you can drag to fontello and it opens it up so you can add more fonts to it and re-export it.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge fontello collections using a text editor by opening the config.json file of one collection and copying the glyphs to the config.json file of the other collection. After you do that, drag (upload) the new merged config.json file to fontello.com and you can then download your new merged collection.

To add new icons, simply drag (upload) the SVG images to fontello.com. In this case you may need fix the paths (fontello will only accept files with a single path) within your SVG files before uploading them. You can do this a free tool called Inkscape by following these steps:

1. Open file
2. Select all
3. Object -> Ungroup
4. Path -> Union
5. Path -> Combine
6. File -> Vacuum Defs
7. Save as -> Plain SVG

If the SVG file has multiple paths that you cannot remove by combining paths, you can use Edit > XMP Editor to remove them. You should only have one path when you are done.

You can also check the svg file output in a text editor. If saved correctly, you should see a single  element and an empty  element.

Answer (score 0):

just drag and drop your svg font to fontello home page. your previous font will be displayed. you can add additional fonts to them and download new font files.